# Is there existing any utilities to get all absolute path of leaf file under a given directory?

Tags: python, directory-structure

os.listdir(path) can return all the files under the directory of the given path. I an wonder if there exists any utility function that can conduct deep traverse and return all the paths of leaf files under a given directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure! You are looking for [os.walk](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk):

```
import os
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for filename in files:
        filename = os.path.join(root, filename)
        print(filename)
```